# How to use iff function inside in dynamic SQL string

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my code, I am facing trouble in using iff function in the Dynamic sql string
The SQL server posting the error as "Incorrect syntax near 'won'." Help me with this.

```
Declare @Colname NVARCHAR (128)
Declare @SQl NVARCHAR(MAX)

set @Colname = N'Channel_Edited'

Set @SQl = N'Select '+@Colname+', Count(WonOpps) as Won, Count(LostOpps) as Lost, Count(OpenOpps) as [open]
From
    (        select '+@Colname+',
                    iif (Stage_Edited = 'won', opp_id,null) WonOpps,
                    iif (Stage_Edited = 'lost', opp_id,null) LostOpps,
                    iif (Stage_Edited = 'open', opp_id,null) OpenOpps

            From CRM_Deal2
            ) as ABC
 Group by '+@Colname

 Exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Place double apostrophes by won, lost and open constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change below part in your code

```
  iif (Stage_Edited = ''won'', opp_id,null) WonOpps,
                    iif (Stage_Edited = ''lost'', opp_id,null) LostOpps,
                    iif (Stage_Edited = ''open'', opp_id,null) OpenOpps
```

Comment: Thanks :) That Worked.